# Override JavaScript NAME property on Angular2 (typescript)

Tags: angular, typescript, draw2d-js

I'm using draw2d on angular2 (draw2d-wrapper). I'm trying extend a class from them.

```
export class Table extends (draw2d.shape.layout.VerticalLayout as { new(): any }) {
    static NAME: "Table";
    /*Some code*/
}
```

on my code when I do 
`var t = new Table();`

the t.NAME property came as "draw2d.shape.layout.VerticalLayout".

Can I override this JavaScript property in a angular2 typescript code?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to access the property on your table instance, it's not really a static property. Simplifying your example, this works:

```
class VerticalLayout {
  NAME = "VerticalLayout";
}

class Table extends VerticalLayout  {  
  NAME = "Table";
}

new Table().NAME; // Table
```

I would expect the same to work for deriving from `draw2d.shape.layout.VerticalLayout`

Comment: That solves partially the problem, now the problem is in a method is a superclass of (draw2d.shape.layout.VerticalLayout) that uses the eval method to create a new instance of the object  `var o = eval("new "+element.type+"()");` when the name is "draw2d....." i have no error but the method that i override on my sub class is not called. When element.type is "Table" i get this error message `"Unable to instantiate figure type 'Tabela' with id…rshal by draw2d.io.json.Reader. Skipping figure.."]`